# Selenium scraping: changing timezone

Tags: python, selenium, timezone, phantomjs, headless-browser

The website I run my headless (PhantomJS) browser through Selenium has different timezone so I get the wrong dates for many entries. Thus my scraped results show the wrong dates/times (i'm in EST, looks like website default is GMT).

I'm scraping from [this](http://www.oddsportal.com/hockey/usa/nhl/results/) website. You can get an idea of how i'm scraping dates through a previous question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261899/selenium-scraping-with-multiple-urls). Note however i'm not currently scraping the times of games so i'd prefer not to incorporate this in a solution.

The same question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708615/wrong-date-associated-with-early-morning-times-scraped-from-weather-website-pyt) but I don't know how to test the 'obvious' solution of checking to see what time the website is defaulting to. I suppose one would request a time from the client and add/subtract hours from my current time? Can someone please tell me how to do that and/or if there's a better way.

Edit: what I want is to change the website scraped data from the default (GMT) to my time (EST). This will avoid having to mess with adding hours; the dates will reflect what they are for me.

Here's as far as i've gotten:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
#from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:/phantomjs.exe')
driver.get('http://www.oddsportal.com/hockey/usa/nhl/results/')

zoneDropDownID = "timezone-content"

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
zoneDropDownElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(zoneDropDownID))
# Select(zoneDropDownID).select_by_visible_text("Eastern") # strobject has no attribute
test = zoneDropDownID.select_by_visible_text("Eastern").click() # TimeOut exception - not found

driver.close()
```

But I can't get it to click. Should I be searching for a class instead?

Comment: In the right upper corner you can select your timezone. I believe EST = GMT-5. You can use selenium to select the correct timezone from the dropdown. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Got it, now I need to work out how to do this with Selenium. Something like: `Select(driver.find_element_by_class("selected")).select_by_value(15).click()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to that url:

```
driver.get('http://www.oddsportal.com/set-timezone/15/')
```

Comment: This answer helped more than the other one. Thanks for responding

Answer (score 4):

A better idea for testing is, to use chromedriver or something similar. The benefit is, that you can check visually, what your script is doing. Here is a sample code (without errohandling) that does what you want.
Please be aware, [chromedriver.exe](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) must be in the same location as the script is.

```js
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en")
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(chrome, 300)

import time

chrome.get("http://www.oddsportal.com/hockey/usa/nhl/results/")

dropdown = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"user-header-timezone-expander")))
dropdown.click()

userHeader = chrome.find_element_by_id('user-header-timezone')
time.sleep(2)
ahref = userHeader.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

for a in ahref:
    print(a.get_attribute("text"))
    if "Eastern Time" in a.get_attribute('text'):
        a.click()
time.sleep(10)
chrome.close()
```