# Change selenium driver timezone

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scraping from this [website](https://www.myfxbook.com/forex-economic-calendar), but the problem is that the times in the selenium chrome webpage are not syncronized with my timezone. I googled and I found some related post here but those solution does not work in my case, probably I'm doing something wrong, I attach part of my attempt.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-translate')
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en")


class FxBook(NewsProvider):
    def get_weakly_news(self) -> Set[News]:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),chrome_options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("https://www.myfxbook.com/forex-economic-calendar")

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

        allId = soup.find_all("tr",attrs={"data-row-id" : True})

        for item in allId[:2]: # 2 just to do some test
          date = item.find("div", class_="align-center calendarDateTd").text
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118971/10586644) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66398560/10586644) and some other things but I get always the wrong timezone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688079/how-do-i-set-a-timezone-in-selenium-chromedriver - Please check the last ans of this thread.

Comment: Already checked and it's in my comment as a link

Comment: Copy of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688079/how-do-i-set-a-timezone-in-selenium-chromedriver